# Help me add Taxonomy to byline

Tags: taxonomy

The following is my code for adding a byline to a post. Can you please explain how I can get my taxonomy onto this. The taxonomy is destination.

```
/*********************
CLEAN BYLINE
*********************/
if ( ! function_exists( 'cb_byline' ) ) {  
    function cb_byline($cb_cat = true, $cb_post_id = NULL, $cb_short_comment_line = false, $cb_posts_on = false) {

    $cb_meta_onoff = ot_get_option('cb_meta_onoff', 'on'); 
    $cb_disqus_code = ot_get_option('cb_disqus_shortname', NULL);
    $cb_byline = $cb_cat_output = $cb_comments = NULL;
    $cb_cats = get_the_category($cb_post_id);

    if ( isset( $cb_cats ) && ( $cb_cat == true ) ) {
        $cb_cat_output = ' <div class="cb-category"><i class="icon-folder-close"></i> ';
        $i = 1;
        foreach($cb_cats as $category) {
            if ( $i != 1 ) { $cb_cat_output .= ', '; }
             $cb_cat_output .= ' <a href="'.get_category_link( $category->term_id ).'" title="' . esc_attr( sprintf( __( "View all posts in %s", "cubell" ), $category->name ) ) . '">'.$category->cat_name.'</a>';
             $i++;
        }
        $cb_cat_output .= '</div>';
    }
    if ( $cb_disqus_code == NULL ) {
         if ( get_comments_number( $cb_post_id ) > 0) {
            if ( $cb_short_comment_line == true ) {
                $cb_comments = ' <div class="cb-comments"><span><i class="icon-comment"></i><a href="' . get_comments_link( $cb_post_id ) . '">' . get_comments_number( $cb_post_id ) . '</a></span></div>';
            } else {

                if ( get_comments_number( $cb_post_id ) == 1) {
                         $cb_comment_line = __('Comment', 'cubell'); 
                } else {
                        $cb_comment_line =  __('Comments', 'cubell');
                }
                $cb_comments = ' <div class="cb-comments"><span><i class="icon-comment"></i><a href="' . get_comments_link( $cb_post_id ) .'">'. get_comments_number( $cb_post_id ) . ' '. $cb_comment_line .'</a></span></div>';

            }
        }
    } else {

        $cb_comments = ' <div class="cb-comments"><span><i class="icon-comment"></i><a href="' . get_permalink( $cb_post_id ) . '#disqus_thread"></a></span></div>';

    }

    $cb_date = ' <div class="cb-date"><i class="icon-time"></i> <time class="updated" datetime="'. get_the_time('Y-m-d', $cb_post_id).'">'. date_i18n( get_option('date_format'), strtotime(get_the_time("Y-m-d", $cb_post_id )) ) .'</time></div>';

    if ( ( $cb_meta_onoff == 'on' ) || ( $cb_posts_on == true ) ) {
        $cb_byline = '<div class="cb-byline">' . $cb_author . $cb_date . $cb_cat_output . $cb_comments . '</div>';
    }

    return $cb_byline;


}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
get_the_term_list( $id, $taxonomy, $before = '', $sep = '', $after = '' );
```

In your case you have to fill in the proper values:

```
$destination = get_the_term_list( 
    $cb_post_id, 
    'destination', 
    ' <div class="cb-destination">', 
    ', ', 
    '</div>' 
);
```

Then add `$destination` to `<div class="cb-byline">`.